# Can't create an outlet connection by drag and drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I'm new to iOS XCode6 ,trying to create a single view app . When I try to create an outlet connection to the label by drag and drop , nothing shows up as you see in the picture below. I did search the web all over to find an answer but nothing worked. I'm working from a text book which is made for beginners,following all instructions and nothing there mentioned about this issue. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks .
[image]

Comment: drag from the referencing outlet circle, also make sure the viewcontroller's class in the storyboard is set to this one you are trying to make the connection to

Comment: I did this and still not working.

Comment: this may help you http://www.codetuition.com/ios-tutorials/connecting-iboutlets-ibactions-the-fast-way/

Comment: This application has a single view so I didn't need the storyboard.In the book it says not to check the storyboard,but the screen I had didn't have any of this option ,have no idea why.It created the storyboard automatically.

Comment: You are not allowed interact with your `LaunchScreen.xib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you select is a LaunchScreen. You can not drag and drop from there into your `viewController`

Select the storyboard,set the class to the right viewController,then you can drag outlets

Set the class to the viewController here
[image]

Then you can drag outlets like this

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more about how to set the class to the right viewController ?When I choose the storyboard all what I get in the custom class menu is the UIView.

Comment: See update,if you create a new project,the first viewController is auto set

Comment: Ah you mean change the class of the "Label" to be ViewController !It's working now ! Thank you so much !I have been frustrated for two days an almost gave up .Thanks again :)

Comment: No,I mean the class of UIViewController,not the class of UILabel.You can see that in the first image I post. I select the  blue area.That is the UIViewController

Comment: Ah yes you are right ,I just changed it and kept the UILabel and it's working right now.So what does the whole process mean and why we have to change the name of the class?

Comment: Because,if you drag a new UIViewController, and you create a class called a `SecondViewController`,you have to set it to the right UIViewController in storyboard so that XCode know this class handle this UIViewController

Comment: Will sure explore more about it.Thank you so much :))